# inline-block elements are line breaking for seemingly no reason?

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

I have some pretty basic HTML/CSS that isn't working as I expect. Basically I have my body setup to be 400px wide. I then have two divs inside of the body with explicit widths of 300px and 100px. Additionally, both of these divs are set to `display: inline-block`. For some reason, the 100px div breaks out of the body's content area and appears below it. I don't know why this is happening. If I set the width from 100px to 96px, it works. However, if I set it to 97px, 98px, 99px, or back to 100px, it doesn't work. I find this behavior very odd. Can someone explain what is going wrong?

Note that I am testing this on Chrome (Beta Channel). Code is below.

The CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 4px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.list-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.button-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="list-container">
</div>

<div class="button-container">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `margin: 0; padding: 0` for both elements? Do they have any `border`s set?

Comment: @David: I checked in chrome developer tools and I don't see any padding, border, or margin for either of these Divs. Additionally, the final computed CSS doesn't seem to include anything unexpected.

Comment: Although this will probably not solve your problem, it's more common to see those two elements floated rather than positioned using inline-block.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because of the way `white-space` collapses in html.

If you remove the line-breaks from between the two `div` elements, everything's fine:

```
<div class="list-container">
</div><div class="button-container">
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tcqYp/).

You could, also, just comment-out the between `div`s:

```
<div class="list-container">
</div><!--

--><div class="button-container">
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tcqYp/1/).

Or even set the `font-size` to zero for the `body` element (but you'll have to redefine it for the child elements, obviously:

```
body {
    margin: 4px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tcqYp/3/).

Comment: Fascinating - I never knew this happened and have been operating under the obviously mistaken belief that whitespace was ignored.  Good to know.

Comment: White-space between `display: block` elements collapses to, essentially, nothing. But between `inline` and `inline-block` elements it collapses to a single white-space character.

Comment: This is great information, thank you. I will use floats instead, as I didn't know inline-blocks were this much of a pain in the rear :)

Comment: Your JS Fiddle demo give me what i needed: `inline-block`; Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility with odd `inline-block` behaviour in Chrome is if you have `text-render: optimizeLegibility` set. I was struggling with inexplicable line-breaks in inline block elements in Chrome, and found that removing `text-render: optimizeLegibility` fixed the problem.

I've had at least [one other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16221871/180500) hard-to-figure-out problem (inexplicable non-rendering of web fonts) that turned out to be caused by `optimizeLegibility` in the past, so from now on that's going to be a prime suspect when things behave strangely in Chrome.

(nb. Even if you don't think you're using it, if you're using a framework like Twitter Bootstrap you may be using it unwittingly)

Comment: This was the cause of the problem for me on an android tablet

Answer (score 0):

It's the margin in your body:

`margin: 4px;`

Because the margin counts as part of the total width. 300px for the first one + 100px for the second div + 8px (4 on either side) for the margin = 408px. That forces the second div down to the next line.

I'm actually kind of surprised that it works at 96. It acts like it's only accounting for the margin on one side. I'd expect it to only work at 92 or below. Either way account for the margin size in the width of your body or set the margin to 0 and that should fix the problem.

Comment: It's not the `margin`, it's the `white-space` (or, at least, it's potentially the `white-space` *as well*)...

Comment: I have already tried removing the margin in the body, however this has no affect on the symptoms of the problem. The margin is *outside* of the content area so actually it plays no role whatsoever in this particular scenario.

Comment: @Robert, see my answer, and JS Fiddle demos. The suggestions work on JS Fiddle, so *presumably* they'd solve your issues too.