# CSS Font smoothing HTML emails

Tags: css, html-email, email-client

CSS font smoothing doesn't seem to be working in my CSS emails.

```
<p style="-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;">Text</p>
```

Are these properties supported in any email clients? I've only tested in Gmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both work, but what you're seeing is a quirk of GMail- it doesn't like css3. There isn't anything to my knowledge you can do about it. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3107/css3-support-in-email-clients/

^dated 2010, and doesn't mention font-smoothing, but it is still css3 and it still holds true for gmail.

Try opening the same email in Apple Mail, or on an iphone/android, and the fonts should be smoothed.

P.S optimizeLegibility is a bad idea, it can crash android < 2.3 and cause problems elsewhere. See below:

[Is it safe to use the CSS rule "text-rendering: optimizelegibility;" on all text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968795/is-it-safe-to-use-the-css-rule-text-rendering-optimizelegibility-on-all-text)