# How to make inline-block in Chrome for Android work properly?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, css

I'm trying to set up a page that looks good in Chrome for Android as well as in desktop Chrome.

I've got it working well in desktop Chrome, as per this screen shot:
[image: Imgur].

The two "Answer Choice" lines, including the red "X" buttons, are in a div (called `answers`). The green "+" button is in the layout **after** the `answers` div. I've applied `display: inline-block` to the `answers` div, and as you can see, it's working as expected.

However, when I try to do this in Chrome for Android, the `inline-block` style doesn't seem to be working properly:

[image: Imgur]

I can confirm that the style **is** being applied (I can use the remote inspector). If I remove the style, the green "+" button moves up a few pixels, showing that it is doing something, just not what I want.

How can I force Chrome on Android to respect the `inline-block` style?

EDIT:  Here's the CSS applicable to the div containing all the answer choices:

```
.answers {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px
}
```

Comment: how could we know without seeing any code?

Comment: Because there's very little other CSS affecting this element. I don't think posting my entire stylesheet will help much. (Plus, it's working fine in desktop Chrome and Firefox...) I will edit the question to show what little CSS I have applied to these elements.

Comment: Maybe there's a min-width on something?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and found the solution on another question about div's and inline-block style. It's because of the way white-space collapses in html. You need to change your html so that the first button's close tag has no space between the second button's open tag.

```
<button class="button1">1
</button><button class="button2">2
</button>
```

See [inline-block elements are line breaking for seemingly no reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284894/inline-block-elements-are-line-breaking-for-seemingly-no-reason?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced inline-block behaving inconsistently on Android as well. While I haven't been able to track down exactly what's going on, in many cases you can get away with using `display: inline`, which renders consistently.

Of course, you cannot use margin on inline elements. To address the vertical positioning, you can use `vertical-align: middle`.

Answer (score -3):

Try to add "!important" to the "display: inline-block;"-attribute. Then it should look like this:

```
display: inline-block !important;
```

Comment: That didn't do anything. I'm pretty sure the style isn't getting overridden, as the element does move a little when I disable that property.